# Making a windows program thumbdrive portable

Tags: windows, portable-applications

I am currently trying to make an application portable.

Where are the common places that an application  puts its settings in a windows machine?

do you know know of any other places besides

-registry

-Currentuser/Application Data

-app folder

?

Comment: You should make your question more clear. Are you asking about apps that run across multiple platforms ("crossplatform") or about apps that run across multiple PCs off a thumbdrive, carrying user data with them?

Comment: Good Point, i also added windows as a tag

Answer (score 4, accepted):

After you go over all the places you could think of, try running your app with [Process Monitor](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb896645.aspx) in the background. Using the right filters, it will show you which registry keys and files have been accessed. And, it will show the exact stack trace of every operation, so you won't have a hard time finding the source of those calls.

Answer (score 0):

Just for completeness - There are a couple of places within the registry (current-user and local-machine).
It depends how the developer stored it.

As sean has said in comment, this also depends on the application framework and windows version. (Thanks sean)

Comment: Also depends on which version of Windows.  On Vista, writes to the app folder will actually hit AppData\Local\VirtualStore.